# MVC & PHP: Mail templates (View) vs Sending (Controller)

Tags: php, email, model-view-controller, registration, contact-form

### **What do I want to do?**

I am trying to create a little application in PHP to manage user requests and registrations. I am not using any MVC framework, but I want to make it following the MVC because I want to scale it and reuse the code of some components.

### **My Question:**

***If the Controller does not manage the View, how can it access the mail's final presentation (content+format) before sending it?***

### **In which guidelines I want to base it?**

I have read some articles about MVC in web applications, and I have intention to meet the following specifications:

- **The Model**:

  > In its simplest form the model stores data which is to be accessed by the view and written to by the controller. The model is the most complex of all the parts of the system and will contain all the logic which is specific to the application and where domain entities that relate to real world concepts (such as "a user" or "an order") are stored. It is the part of the application which takes data (from any source) and processes it. The model also handles all data access and storage. It has no knowledge of any controllers or views which may use it.
- **The View**:

  > The view contains all the display logic. In PHP it will be the part of the application which generates the HTML. It has direct access to the Model and can query the model to get its data. The View can create callbacks to its controller (for example a clicking a button in the view would trigger an action in the controller). In MVC the view queries the model to request its own data.
- **The Controller**:

  > The controller takes user input and updates the model where required. Where there is no user interaction (e.g. where a static data set is displayed and will be the same every time), no controller should be necessary. It is important to note that the controller is not a mediator or gateway between the view and the model. The view gets its own data from its model. The controller accesses the model but does not contain any display logic itself. All the controller does is respond to user input.
  >   It's important to note that the controller is not in charge of instantiating the model or the view. Each controller is linked to a single instance of a view and a single instance of a model.

The above specification could be summarized with the [following diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY12l.jpg)

### Trying to do it with Mailing Case

So I assume that the Controller is the one that is going to send the email(s) and the View is the one that is going to prepare the email(s) presentation.

The more detailed version of the previous diagram, [adapted to the mailing case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYypy.jpg)  (***please, notice the discontinuous arrow with an interrogation, as it is where my question lies***):

Is there anyway to keep the following **general program flow**?:

```php
//initiate the triad
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($model);
$controller->{$UserRequest};
echo $view->output();
```

I do not find any solution to this. Is there any way to proceed that I cannot find?

Thank you guys for your help...

Comment: Any idea on this? Perhaps `email` should not be seen as having its specific templates in the View Layer? Or, perhaps the `email` should rather be seen as pure text that does not offer a UI? (an should be triggered, therefore, directly by the Controller itself)

Answer (score 0):

Mail is generally considered as a part of "helper class". 
Indeed, mail should be sent through the controller class, but defined in helpers for more clarity.
 You can use phpMailer for example (really easy to use in MVC).

Comment: Could you please, provide an example of the sequence where the three components are involved and the _View_ renders the email format by using one of its templates with the data queried to the _Model_, and then calls back the _Controller_ to send the email? I think that your proposal entails a final _call back_ from _View_ to its _Controller_, with no user interaction there, with the aim to finally sending the composed email to the user initiating the request